# Media queries for iPhone 4/4S(landscape) being overlapped with media queries for iPhone 6 Plus(landscape)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I set the media queries for iPhone 6 plus, for landscape orientation, it renders fine, but it disturbs the layout of controls for iPhone 4S.How can I avoid this? I know that this is because of the padding I have set to override bootstrap's .well, but if I dont set it, there is a lot of unwanted space within the controls.

Here is my css code:

/*iPhone 4 and 4S landscape*/

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 

h1, .h1{
    font-size:26px;
}


.well{
    padding: 59px;
}
}
```

/*iPhone 6 Plus in landscape*/

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 

.mt-4x{
    margin-top:20px !important;
}

.well{
    padding: 175px;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant html too?

Comment: Change /iPhone 6 Plus in landscape/ media query (min-device-width : 414px)   into (min-device-width : 479px)  then it won't overlap

Comment: @Skelly posted the html code

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @AdnanAkram can you please explain your answer. If I change the min-width for this particular media query, I will have to change for all other media queries that are also overlapping

Comment: The problem with you media query is on first i means /iPhone 4 and 4S landscape/ you are telling browser that apply these CSS styles within 320px to 480px width

Then in iPhone 6 Plus in landscape/  you are telling browser to apply css styles from 414px to 736px width that means you are asking browser to override style

in result /iPhone 6 Plus in landscape/  style will apply on iPhone4 screen to when screen width is more then 414px

Comment: @Ismall that code is 6 years old. This new code works great Device Specific CSS Media Queries  https://gist.github.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c

Comment: @mlegg the media queries that are there in the link you posted are the exact ones that I have used,please go through the question again

Comment: @AdnanAkram I dont think changing the original min-device-width is the right approach of doing it, and anyways I tried it, it does not give me the required output

Comment: @sumedha in your post I only see media queries for iphone4 and iphone6 plus. The link I gave is media queries for every device and size currently out there.

Comment: @mlegg thats because I had problems only with media queries for iphone 4 and iphone 6 plus

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this into your css media queries for the iPhones?

```css
/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* 
  iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
  It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.
*/

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}
```

Comment: does the site work right now? if not post a link to your page please

Comment: the media queries that you posted in your answer are exactly the same ones that I posted in my question. The only difference is that you posted for all the screens  and I have posted only for iPhone 4s and 6 plus, because those were the only ones that were giving me a problem. I asked for an alternate way to do this so that the media queries dont overlap. And I cannot post the link because I cannot host the website untill I fix this issue

Comment: I have down voted your answer because it contains the same media queries that are already there in the question and thats exactly what is causing the problem.